# Django add methods to django.db.models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a created a table that stores session environments for a program that has to manage authentication via multiple 3rd party SSO authentication frameworks.

What I am trying to do is create a new method inside of my `UserEnvironemntSession` object so that I can do:

```
from authentication import UserEnvironementSession, User, Environement

#user and environement will be configured as part of a session somewhere and
#This is just an example

user = User.objects.get(username="username")
environment = User.objects.get(pk=2)

ues = UserEnvironmentSession.objects.get(user=user, environment=environement)

user_session = ues.create_user_sso_session()
```

The above code would look for a session for the given user/session objects then create a new authenticated session for the user.

What I have done is created a new method in my `UserEnvironementSession` class as follows

```
class UserEnvironmentSession(models.Model):
    user          = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name = "userenvsession_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    environment   = models.ForeignKey("Environment", related_name = "userenvsession_environement", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create_user_sso_session(self):
        '''
             Generates a new user object from the UserEnvironmentSession.
             It will attempt to set the User.token and authenticate. If the auth token is expired.
             It will throw an error that can be used to initiate a new login process.
        '''

        #Set up our SSO authentication
        auth = SSO.authentication.SSOAuthentication()
        auth.domain = self.environment.domain
        auth.auth_header = self.environment.header

        #configure our user with our authenticator and session token
        self.user.authenticator = auth
        self.user.token = self.session_token

        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            #If token is vaild is_authenticated will return true. We need to set up a user session with
            # our session_token header and set it to our created user object.
            import requests
            user.session = requests.session()
            user.session.headers[self.environment.header] = self.session_token
        else:
            #If the token is invalid we throw an SSO.errors.LoginFailureError
            raise SSO.errors.LoginFailureError("The token for this UserSession has expired, so we need to login again.")
```

I figured the above would work but this leaves me with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/virtualenv/cps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/virtualenv/cps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/virtualenv/cps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/virtualenv/cps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/virtualenv/cps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/course_producer_suite/authentication/models.py", line 27, in <module>
class UserEnvironmentSession(models.Model):
  File "/Users/rchristensen1/Development/Python/course_producer_suite/authentication/models.py", line 41, in UserEnvironmentSession
     auth.domain = self.environment.domain
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: That should work. Have you checked for indentation problems? Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: You have various spellings of `UserEnvironmentSession`... can you verify that none of those errors are actually in your code and maybe correct it here?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks that was what it was some indentation issues...